# Dynamically populate one Django Form field based on selection in another

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model with a list of choices as follows:

`models.py`

```
class Choice_class(models.Model):

    options = (
        ('None', 'none'),
        ('one', 'one'),
        ('two', 'two'),
        ('three', 'three'),
    )

    option_values = (
        ('None', 0),
        ('one', 1),
        ('two', 2),
        ('three', 3),
    )

    user_choice = models.CharField(max_length = 5, choices = options, default = 'None')
    choice_value = models.IntegerField()
```

and a form as follows:
`forms.py`

```
class Choice_class(ModelForm):

    options = (
        ('None', 'none'),
        ('one', 'one'),
        ('two', 'two'),
        ('three', 'three'),
    )

    option_values = (
        ('None', 0),
        ('one', 1),
        ('two', 2),
        ('three', 3),
    )

    user_choice = models.CharField(max_length = 5, choices = options, default = 'None')
    choice_value = models.IntegerField(default = option_values[#BASED ON USER CHOICE IN FIELD ABOVE] )
```

I'd like to populate the `choice_value` field with a default value from `option_values` based on what user selects for the `user_choice` field.

I'd rather not do this through js (although it's an option) because I feel like there should be a way to do this through the framework in the same form.

I realise that I also have the option of doing the logic for this in `views.py`:

```
if choice_value == 'None': 
   '''populate with default value based on user_choice as defined by dict in views file etc'''
```

but I'd rather do this within the form if possible.

Thanks in advance if you have any pointers.

Comment: Did you want this to dynamically change even if there is no instance on the form? Or only change it depending on the value of `user_choice` when an instance is passed?

Comment: When instance is passed, populate `choice_value` with a default based on `user_choice` if no other value for `choice_value` is provided. The more I think about it though, either handling this in the DOM or postprocessing in the view may be the only viable ways forward. In my head, there should be a way to do this in `forms.py` file to keep my views slim, but the alternatives present themselves more readily.

Comment: Yeah you would need to load the form, the view and the template again when `user_choice` changes.